# Canceling an OpenLayers.Map current panTo tween if user begins dragging map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, openlayers

I've noticed that if the user drags the map before the panTo function completes, the map will continue to pan in the previous pan direction.

Here's a quick jsfiddle with a high pan duration to make the effect easy to reproduce:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8kK4/58/

```
map.panTo( xy ); // code for jsfiddle link
```

Is there any straight forward way to cancel the current panning event if the user begins to drag the map?

Comment: Interesting question. I had a go using this.panTween.stop() inside a moveend callback, which just made matters worse. I found a thread from one of the developers from several years ago with your exact issue, but no resolution, sadly. Will have another go after work.

Comment: I think I have fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, though I'm not sure if this is the best way. Basically, what I did is put a call to panTween.stop in the map's moveend event, but also set the panTween's callback to null, as otherwise, the loop continues -- see the OpenLayers.Tween stop`function here: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Tween.js

In summary, I added these three lines at the end of your init function:

```
map.events.register('moveend', map, function(){           
        this.panTween.callbacks=null;
        this.panTween.stop();            
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8kK4/62/

Comment: Great! Is there anyway to have it cancel on the start of a move rather than the end? I tried setting it to a 'move' event, but that causes the pan to interrupt itself...

Comment: @Pondwater. You could try movestart instead of moveend. Yes, the general problem you have here is that both pan and drag call the same callbacks, so it is hard to not have them interrupt/interfere with each other.

Comment: Hmm movestart seems to interrupt it as well. Oh well, at least I know how to stop it, i'll have to work in my own callback mechanic. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean drag start?

Comment: I added your code above to a mousedown event callback on the maps element which gave me my desired effect.